# Draw multiple polar graphs in different positions on a common coordination system - Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, polarplot

I am trying to plot several polar graphs in a `tikzpicture`.
The idea is to plot the same function but for different parameters.
An idea of what I am trying to achieve can be seen below

[image]

Although I am able to draw all these individual functions in one single polar plot, I don't know how to draw each if them separately in a common canvas.

So, at the moment I am able to produce the following

[image]

using the code seen below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}
    \foreach \atwo in {0, 0.4, ..., 2.4}
        \foreach \afour in {-0.6, -0.4, ...,1.8}
            \addplot+[mark=none,domain=0:720,samples=200] 
                {1 + \atwo*(3*cos(x)^2-1)/2 - \afour*(35*cos(x)^4-30*cos(x)^2+3)/8};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The goal is therefore to draw a set of axes (`a2 , a4`) and in each node the corresponding polar plot without the polar axes.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the loops outside the `polaraxis` environment, and use the `at` parameter for the `axis` to move the axes around. The outer axis and ticklabels has to be done manually though. For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach[count=\i] \atwo in {0, 0.4, ..., 2.4} {
    \node [below] at (\i,0) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\atwo}};
    \foreach [count=\j] \afour in {-0.6, -0.4, ...,1.8} {
       \ifnum\i=1
        \node [left] at (0,\j) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\afour}};
        \fi
        \begin{polaraxis}[
           at={(\i*1cm,\j*1cm)},
           hide axis,
           scale only axis,
           width=1cm,
           name=ax-\i-\j,
           anchor=center
          ]
            \addplot+[mark=none,domain=0:720,samples=200] 
                {1 + \atwo*(3*cos(x)^2-1)/2 - \afour*(35*cos(x)^4-30*cos(x)^2+3)/8};
       \end{polaraxis}
    }}
    \node [draw,fit=(ax-1-1)(ax-7-12)] (ax) {};
    \node [left=1.2cm] at (ax.west) {$\alpha_4$};
    \node [below=1cm] at (ax.south) {$\alpha_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```